# Trying to perform this logic in Microstrategy

Tags: sql, microstrategy

```sql
count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN enrollment_status = 'ACTIVE' AND enroll_end_date is null and enroll_start_date <= TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)-1) 
THEN customer_id END) AS ACTIVE_MEMEMERS,
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The query is same as :

```
select count(distinct customer_id) from table where enrollment_status = 'ACTIVE' AND enroll_end_date is null and enroll_start_date <= TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)-1)
```

You can try the below approach :

1. Create 3 filter based on the WHERE clause of the query.
2. Create 1 metric COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID).
3. Add the filters inside the metric.